# What is the running time of the fragment?

Tags: java, data-structures

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = i; j <= n; j++)
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
            s1++;

for (int q = 0; q < n * n; q++ )
    for(int p = 0; p < q; p++)
        s1++;
```

these are two o(n^3) so it is o(n^6) right? I was running the program and it seems to be o(n^5)

Comment: if we are speaking about o notation, then it is just exponential

Comment: if you want to check the execution time then you take the system time at the begining and at the end so the difference endtime-starttime

Comment: Doing two O(n^3) things doesn't make it O(n^6). If they are executed one after the other (as here), it's still O(n^3).

Comment: hi @vmrvictor, why do you say exponential tho?

Comment: Your indentation here is ambiguous about what you expect the code to actually do. You should really use `{}`.

Comment: Wow still o(n^3)? I am clearly not understanding algorithms.. I don't understand how the whole fragmant will be o(n^3)

Comment: It is not exponential.  It is polynomial.

Comment: can someone explain why this is the case?  Doing two O(n^3) things doesn't make it O(n^6). If they are executed one after the other (as here), it's still O(n^3)

Comment: I wanted to say polynomial sorry I mixed....

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying with the second fragment being o(n^4) now, it makes sense

Comment: The two loops happen one after the other. If I give you 2^3 = 8 balls, and then give you another 2^3 = 8 balls, would you have 2^3 + 2^3 = 2.2^3 = 16 balls or 2^3\*2^3 = 2^6 = 64 balls? But yes, the second one is actually n^4.

Answer (score 1):

The first code block has `O(n^3)` complexity, but the second one is `O(n^4)` due to `n*n` limits.

So overall time is `O(n^3+n^4) = O(n^4)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to empirically demonstrate the complexity of this program.

- The total complexity is determined by the number of loop iterations.
- Each loop iteration increments `s1`.
- So the *value* of `s1` at the end of the program is the number of loop iterations.

So:

1. Add a print statement at the end and print `s1`.
2. Graph it as a function of `n`.
3. Work out is the curve is a fit for a `C * n^2`, `C * n^3` or whatever curve ... as `n` gets larger.

---

If you want to prove the complexity, analyze it and then do some algebra / proof by induction to derive an *analytical formula* for the value of `s1` as a function of `n`.  Then determine the complexity class from the analytical formula.

Hint: if the formula is a polynomial in `n` of degree `p`, then the complexity class will be `O(n^p)`.

---

Measuring the time can give you misleading results because there are various factors that can distort the timings, including JVM warmup effects.

Printing the value of `s1` doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the loops are `O(n^3)` and there are two loops executed one after the other so the overall complexity is `O(2*n^3)` which is the same as **`O(n^3)`**.

This

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = i; j <= n; j++)
            for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
                for (int q = 0; q < n * n; q++)
                    for (int p = 0; p < q; p++)
                        s1++;
```

would be `O(n^6)`.

Answer (score 0):

The overall complexity of the above snippet of code will be O(n^3) + O(n^4) = O(n^4) [Worst Case Complexity in Big-O notation].

Answer (score 0):

Your first `for` loop iterates `n` times (from `0` to `n - 1`), so it has a time complexity of **O(n)** (constant values are omitted).

The second one iterates `n` times as well, but it does it for each iteration of the first loop.
That makes it **O(n * n)** in total so far.

Then the inner most `for` loop iterates `j` times, which equals `n` in the worst case, so it iterates `n` times and that makes the first nesting loop block have a time complexity of **O(n * n * n) = O(n^3)**.

The following block is a separate one. It's time complexity will not be multiplied with the first, it will be added instead.
Its first loop has a complexity of **O(n * n)** due to iterating while `q < n * n`. For each of its iterations, the inner loop is executed and runs `q` times, which is **O(n * n - 1) = O(n * n)** in the worst case (last iteration).

If my calculation is correct (I don't really know, please review it and suggest edits), then the code has a time complexity of

**O(n^3) + O(n^2 * n^2) = O(n^3) + O(n^4) = O(n^4)**

Comment: yes that makes complete sense I understand the second fragment being o(n^4) now

Comment: Good! Try to resolve those tasks with pen and paper. Running the code does not give you the *exact* time complexity.